# space between angular material not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material, frontend

I'm trying to apply 'space between center' in a row, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="space-between center" hide-xs>
            <div layout="column">
                <a>{{ $ctrl.locale.f_a_whydonate }}</a>
                <a>Johan Huizingalaan</a>
                <a>1066VH Amsterdam</a>
            </div>
            <div layout="column" >
                <a>KvK:</a>
                <a>RSIN:</a>
                <a>T:</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any ideas how I could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in `layout-sm="column"`, so if you remove it.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" hide-xs>
        <div layout="column">
            <a>{{ $ctrl.locale.f_a_whydonate }}</a>
            <a>Johan Huizingalaan</a>
            <a>1066VH Amsterdam</a>
        </div>
        <div layout="column" >
            <a>KvK:</a>
            <a>RSIN:</a>
            <a>T:</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It will align fine, look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/g3hhw4r9/1/)

But it depends of what do you want. I think you just was testing on small screen, and you was getting a column align insead of row